# How to create a sidebar panel in OpenOffice?

Tags: java, user-interface, sdk, panel, openoffice.org

I want to create an OpenOffice.org plug-in that adds a sidebar.
I have successfully installed OpenOffice.org, OpenOffice.org SDK and NetBeans OpenOffice plug-in.

I am familiar with Java, AWT and Swing, so no need to explain these concepts to me.

Now, I want to create a sidebar Panel(or JPanel) in OpenOffice.org Writer application.
How can I do this? It would be in the left and fill all available height(while using a fixed width).

Any idea on how to implement this? I have no OpenOffice.org plug-in past experience.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is currently not possible through the OpenOffice.org API. You can create menus, toolbars and dialogs. You cannot create dockable windows or panels via UNO. See: [GUI Chapter in the Dev Guide](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/GUI/Graphical_User_Interfaces).

Exposing this capability through the API is under active development and I suggest you join the api-dev@openoffice.org mailing list to stay on top of things.

The specific feature you asked for was already discussed there and it was suggested that it would be made available with a future update to OpenOffice 3.0. See [post in the list archive](http://api.openoffice.org/servlets/ReadMsg?list=dev&msgNo=20716).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there's an easy answer for this. OO.o provides [their dev guide here](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/OpenOffice.org_Developers_Guide). It appears once you create an UNO component to their spec you can use:

> Arbitrary objects written in Java or
>   C++ [and then] can be called from the user
>   interface, display their own GUI, and
>   work with the entire application.

That sounds like what you want to do. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

It's possible since version 4.0.
See https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Sidebar